# cannot open php file

Tags: php, file-format

i have downloaded some php files (it's a content management system) but i can't open them. it appears that they contain binary data. this is what i get when i open them using a text editor:
Zend20020623011793334417xù
ں2ف=كڈإ™m{Orvƒًè¢9 ­ف]UفU0زع^ہ€eo.’ذî™éفïىجhzcë‌ن7,‏xAœگrBBو$89¯‘<"‌ٍs~±B¤كغتز‎Zء¤ص€1c‍Xû‡ûû×O¦أل¼\آ=o…ر¨ّzـ;^´>®é3ُ`éJہإً_±w[ƒٍµh‍يŒٍE6Ovئس~:.$َügLk,{+»9*گ~m.إ5طû¤ْW%&&aد؛fجMe´?›خة<ƒط<_$o¦َ—Q^4ûJ§{ç/‍صg}u¥kڈnFق0غM2‏#5شl\‏ظو›—.©3 ق?h+<Wٍ9LkئPïھة¤4ےbإ9…ھ   â8”8'´‘گwٍشQf~[أي­Bى}VC‘  هNç،Œح]ڈق~[ƒ‰ف:ô¾6Wںنüو–¤‍£ôُe½ئـة÷g%ت»®-­ىلƒپآڈUˆ%©يئ‘B~نKٍ©,ةgڑCLاcپء¼اثYiآ9†`ںئأ,?5طفمjک'g»³²ص_Jں&÷èQM+ƒZS=c¾03¥–xwجMB~­TN±‹`قƒ²
(there is much more, about 50 lines)
what is this? i have never worked with Zend, is it some kind of compression? how can i open and edit these files?

Comment: some sites trying to "hide" their code, it is like compiling the script but not.

Comment: See [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/in-depth).

Comment: yes it is the Zend Guard. thank you everyone.

Comment: zend guard or ioncube. any of them will produce something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file appears to be encoded by Zend guard. You probably cannot decode it. 
Here is something you can read on http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Answer (score 0):

Encoded PHP file. Protecting their source code